# Can you please tell me these Locale Parameter's Meaning?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, d-bus

## output of my env command

```
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=2
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8

XDG_VTNR=1
XAUTHORITY=/home/alamin/.Xauthority

COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_SESSION_ID=1

LESS=-R
WINDOWPATH=1
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8

LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8

TERMINATOR_DBUS_NAME=net.tenshu.Terminator20x1a6021154d881c
VTE_VERSION=4402
TERMINATOR_DBUS_PATH=/net/tenshu/Terminator2


LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:


XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

All this following configuration refers to en_US.UTF-8. What these configuration means?

1. LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
2. LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
3. LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
4. LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
5. LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
6. LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
7. LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
8. LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
9. LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
10. LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8

which parameters are doing what

Comment: One question per question, please.  Scattershot questions do not help people who look for answers in the future.

Comment: @JdeBP I have updated as per as you said

Answer (score 1):

The `LC_*` variables relate to localization.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software) for more information about locale.

The `DBUS` variables relate to the Desktop Bus.  See https://dbus.freedesktop.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus for more information about DBUS.

The `Xauthority` file is used to store credentials in cookies used by xauth for authentication of X11 windowing system sessions. Once an X session is started, the cookie is used to authenticate connections to that specific display. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization for more information.